# Exception.ToString() doesn't contain the full StackTrace information

Tags: c#, exception

The code is compiled in debug mode.
I catch an Exception and print it with:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
}
```

I expect to see the full stack trace but I get only one row:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at FullClassName.UpdateLink(FileVersione Obj) in C:\path\Code.cs:line 137

Where is the call stack?

```
internal void UpdateLink(FileVersione Obj)
{
    TipoFile tf;
    JobManager.CommonClasses.BusinessObjects.Archivio.FileInfo fi;
    try
    {
        fi = Obj.FileInfo;      <--- Null exception here!!!
        tf = fi.TipoFile;     
        .......................
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.TraceError("UpdateLink Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

There are two methods that call the function:

```
 private void UpdateLinks()
        {
            FileVersione fv;
            while (true)
            {
                fv = (FileVersione)_UpdateLinksQueue.Dequeue();
                this.UpdateLink(fv);
            }
        }
```

OR:

```
 private void UpdateLinks(FileInfo file, bool recursive, int depth)
        {
            ServerDIFileVersione asfd;
            IEnumerable<FileLink> links;
            asfd = (ServerDIFileVersione)FileVersione.StdDataInterface;
            asfd.UpdateLink(file.VersioneAttuale);
            if (recursive && depth<10)
            {
                links = file.Relazioni;
                foreach (FileLink link in links)
                {
                    if (link.Figlio != null)
                        UpdateLinks(link.Figlio, recursive, ++depth);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the code like on that path? Also, can you show us the code that is actually throwing the exception (and possibly rethrowing?)

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I agree with Patrick, most of the time this behavior is due to a `catch` block that performs `throw ex` instead of plain `throw`. Double-check that `UpdateLink()` does not do that.

Comment: How do you call the method?

Comment: What's the output of `Trace.TraceError(ex.StackTrace);` ?

Comment: The output is only two rows, (as I have written):
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at FullClassName.UpdateLink(FileVersione Obj) in C:\path\Code.cs:line 137